# Combining two records via Group By

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm still new and learning in Access vba and appreciate if you can help me with my current scenario.

I have developed a code in VBA which pull the data from a table named `Tblsrce`

```
sqlStr = "SELECT zYear, zMonth, Product, Sum(Dollar) as totalAmt FROM Tblsrce "& _
             "WHERE fruits IN (NOT NULL, '" & Replace(strFruits, ", ", "', '")
             "GROUP BY zYear, zMonth, Product;"
```

The usual data that the field `fruits` contains Mango, Apples, Cherry, Banana, etc.

`strFruits` is a `variable` that came from users (which is separated by comma if they want to pull more than 1 fruit).

However, I got a problem with it when there are 2 related fruits with different name (e.g. Red Apple and Green Apple) which i need to combine. Is there any way I can `Group By` those records and tag them as Apples in the current query that i have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use conditionals like the [`switch function`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?CorrelationId=5c1444e4-7ced-4cce-8941-a3fd2c2c7f9a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA001228918) to calculate some fruit group field.

```
Switch(
  Product='Red Apple', 'Apple'
  Product='Green Apple', 'Apple'
  Product='Orange', 'Citrus') As ProductGroup
```

You can then use that field in a higher level query:

```
Select zYear, zMonth, ProductGroup,
       Count(*)
From
  (Select f.*, 
          Switch( .... ) 
   From Fruits f)
Group By zYear, zMonth, ProductGroup
```

Of course it would be easier if this data isn't calculated dynamically in the query like this, but instead is stored in a separate table, so you know a product group for each of the products. That's also way easier to maintain (just add data instead of modify a query), and probably performs better.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to research about `switch` and will weight what is the most practical and efficient way among the 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but you would have to have an additional table where you list all fruits, and their groups. Then you can join that in, and group by the groups.

Sample structure:

```
  Fruit       | FruitCategory 
+-------------+---------------+
| Red apple   | Apple         |
+-------------+---------------+
| Green apple | Apple         |
+-------------+---------------+
| Banana      | Banana        |
+-------------+---------------+
```

You can prepopulate the table with a quick `SELECT DISTINCT Fruits from Tblsrce` and insert that in both columns, and then adjust the categories where you want.